# UICollection crash Invalid update: invalid number of sections.

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

The number of sections contained in the collection view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the collection view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 0 deleted).

Comment: show some code of UICollectionView delegates methods. Which number of items did you returns?

Comment: This happens because you called `tableView.insertSections(...)` and `tableView.reloadData()` without updating the `func numberOfSections(...)` return number

Answer (score 2):

Are you basing your `numberOfSections` off a model of some sort? What's happening is you're inserting a section into your table view somewhere, reloading your table view data, and then the app is crashing because `numberOfSections` does not equal `The number of sections contained in the collection view after the update`.

Without seeing your code it's hard to pinpoint where the problem is, but I would do a look for where you're inserting a section and figure out how to update your `numberOfSections` accordingly.

A basic example would be having a stored variable like

`var sectionsCount = 1`

and when you insert a section, you can do `sectionsCount = sectionsCount + 1` , reload your tableView data, and have :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sectionsCount.count
    }
```

Remember you always have to update your model that you're basing your table view off of BEFORE you reload the data.